# How are Chrome Extension's weekly users counted? Is it the number of users who have it installed? Or the one's clicking on popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Just wondering what is meant by "Weekly users" in Chrome Webstore? Is it the number of users who have clicked on the popup? Or does it also count if the users are just browsing while the Content Script is at work? What happens if an extension uses both content script and popup?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[According to](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-apps/Sie4cmSTZmk/d-YJtCdcvW0J) Joe Marini (lead Developer relations for Chrome apps/extensions/CWS):

> The number [of weekly users] you see in the Chrome Web Store is **the amount of users whose Chrome browser has checked for an update of your app within the last week**. It is not the number of people who have installed your item.

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar Disabled extensions will also be auto-updated. In Chromium's source code, there's even an [unit test to verify that this really happens](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/updater/extension_updater_unittest.cc?revision=275413&view=markup#l1765).

Comment: @RobW - do you have any clue of what is the use of this information? Why do I need to know how many checks chrome made and how this can help me?

Comment: Just noticed this in the new chrome store dashboard regarding "weekly users" - "The approximate number of Chrome browsers that loaded the item in the past seven days. This includes enabled, disabled, and unknown statuses of the item."