# Chrome webstore - extensions download statistic

Tags: google-chrome-extension

One way to see - how many people downloaded your extension - is to look at statistic in  Chrome webstore.
Another way is to add inside background.js the chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener and send information on server each time, when somebody installed an extension.

My problem is that the information, collected by both these ways - is not similar.

Number of downloads, presented in Chrome webstore is less, than number of installations, collected by second way (for unique ip-addresses).
Why? Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Are you comparing apples with oranges? The numbers in the Chrome Web Store are not total downloads (unlike the Play store), but the total number of weekly numbers. Can you share the numbers that you're seeing? E.g. X unique IP addresses in Y days, or Z unique IP addresses in the past 7 days.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks, but still not clear.
At current moment - number of downloads in webstore is 96.
Number of installations on unique ip-addresses at last 7 days, collected by   second method is 166.
Does it mean, that 70 users uninstalled an extension?

Answer (score 2):

chrome store also takes into account the uninstalls, while your method only counts installs.

you can also detect uninstalls by setting the url to open on uninstall and tally it on your server. see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL

with that, the numbers will match closer. still not perfect as the store takes sometimes weeks to add the stats for a day.

Answer (score 2):

The number of unique IP addresses is not a reliable indicator for users, because users may be using a dynamic address (instead of a static IP address that does not change), and multiple users may be sharing an IP address (behind a NAT or proxy).
And [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) is not just triggered upon a new installation of your extension, but also when the browser/extension is updated.

So, your way of counting unique users is flawed (and given the small number of users, it is likely that your method is overestimating the number of users).

---

The Chrome Web Store dashboard (for developers only) provides the number of *daily* installations (probably measured by counting the number of on-demand CRX downloads).

---

The Chrome Web Store publicly shows the number of weekly users ([measured by counting the number of update checks per week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248397/how-are-chrome-extensions-weekly-users-counted-is-it-the-number-of-users-who-h)).
This number is **not** the number of **active** weekly users, and probably over-estimates the number of actual users.
For example, I have an extension that used to have 1.7k users. Because the extension became obsolete, I published an update that sends a ping to my server and removes the extension itself (using [`chrome.management.uninstallSelf`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstallSelf)). Every week, I receive *at most* a few pings, yet the CWS claims that the extension has about 400 weekly users (these users probably disabled my extension; consequently the extension cannot remove itself but Chrome still checks for updates).

---

### Accurately counting number of users

If you want to know the number of installations, look at the CWS dashboard. If you want to continue to use the `onInstalled` method, at the very least check whether `details.reason === 'install'`.

If you want to have the most reliable indicator of "user", generate a random identifier and store it in `chrome.storage.sync`. Include this ID in requests to the server (for sample code, see [Getting unique ClientID from chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822170/getting-unique-clientid-from-chrome-extension)).

Recently, I introduced server-pings in one of my extensions, to measure the number of users per Chrome version at a given day/week. In this efforts, I prioritized the privacy of users over the accuracy of statistics (by storing the random ID in `localStorage` (which is not synchronized) and refreshing this ID at every major browser update).
If you want to learn more about the code behind it, see https://github.com/Rob--W/pdfjs-telemetry.